# How to update variable number inside of eventlistner with condinitional statement

Tags: javascript

Please excuse me as if this seems like a simple question. I  want to update the sum every time the space bar key is pressed down along with updating the innerHTML. Whenever I press the spacebar it just concatenates my sum variable instead of simply adding it.

HTML

```
<div class="sec1 sec">
    <h1>Spacebar Challenge</h1>
</div>
<div class="sec2 sec">
    <p>
        You have hit the spacebar <span>0</span> times.
    </p>
    <div class='button'><button>Restart</button> </div>
</div>
<div class="sec3 sec"></div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

JS

```
let span = document.querySelector("span")

document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    let sum = 0
    if (e.code === "Space") {
        sum += 1
    }

    span.innerHTML += sum

})
```

Comment: You are concatenating the sum to the current innerHTML: `span.innerHTML += sum`, you can use `span.innerHTML = sum` if you just want to update it - also note that `innerText` or `textContent` is better to use than `innerHTML` if you're not adding a HTML string

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
let span = document.querySelector("span")
let sum = 0

document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  if (e.code === "Space") {
    sum += 1
  }

  span.innerHTML = sum

})
```

```html
<div class="sec1 sec">
  <h1>Spacebar Challenge</h1>
</div>
<div class="sec2 sec">
  <p>
    You have hit the spacebar <span>0</span> times.
  </p>
  <div class='button'><button>Restart</button> </div>
</div>
<div class="sec3 sec"></div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```